# How to make width of form equal to width of input fields within on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/slugwarden/VGPk4/1/

```
form { display: inline-block; }
```

...seems to work on IE and Firefox. However, a little bit of extra space is added to the right side of the input fields on Chrome.

Basically, I want the width of the form to be the same as the width of the text input fields (which will be the widest elements in the form) so that I can right or left align other elements in the form to the right or left edges on the input fields.

Any known workaround for this?

Comment: You could just set the form width to a fixed 286px. http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/VGPk4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `width:100%` and `box-sizing:border-box`. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/z7VaJ/)

```
input {
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: .5em;
    font-family: sans-serif; /* IE - make input text/password fields same size */

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
    width:100%;
}
```

Note: Box-sizing works back to IE8.

Comment: This works flawlessly and seems semantically closest to what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you for bringing the `box-sizing` property to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

as user3212461 says , you need to set `font-size` down to `0` (I do `0.01px`) , then reset it to childs.

---

This is a typical chrome behavior, adding an extra space at end of lines.

It could be at begining actually. It renders the white-space in between inline elements from html.

---

For the floatting button, `margin:0` will do :

---

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VGPk4/4/)**

---

CSS update:

```
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
input {
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: .5em;
    font-family: sans-serif; /* IE - make input text/password fields same size */
}
form {
    border: thin dashed purple; /* visualization */
    display: inline-block;/* inline-table works too */
    font-size:0.1px; /* make sure it is applied , 0 might be rejected by browser for accessibility/readability reasons */
}
button {
    font-size: large;
    float: right;
    margin:0; /* simple reset */
}
p {
    width: 400px;
}
b {
    font-size:16px;/* fallback for rem units */
    font-size:1rem;
}
```

inline-table version with `<br/>` removed : http://jsfiddle.net/VGPk4/5/

Answer (score 0):

Floating the inputs will fix it. Seems a bit hacky though.

Answer (score 0):

```
form {
    border: thin dashed purple; /* visualization */
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
}

form b {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

add font-size: 0; to form.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/VGPk4/3/)

Comment: The caveat to this is that whitespace now applies to the form. The amount of whitespace between elements varies per browser and can mess with layouting. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: can you please clarify this? with example on codepen or jsfiddle of "mess with layouting". ty

Comment: Don't really have a moment for a jsfiddle. But it you're using `display: inline-block` to create two columns with in a fixed container, the whitespace between the two is rendered different between browsers. In Chrome, it might render as two columns, but in FF the whitespace may force the second column to a second row.

Comment: i believe you're wrong. parent container has a font-size: 0; so it won't be any whitespace in any browser.